# Why won't the count occurrence of this array in python work?

Tags: python

```
Grade = [""]*20
A=0
B=0
C=0
D=0
F=0

for index in range (20):
    Grade[index]=str(input("Input A, B, C, D or F: "))

print (Grade)

for index in range(20):
    if Grade[index]==A:
        A=A+1
    elif Grade[index]==B:
        B=B+1
    elif Grade[index]==C:
        C=C+1
    elif Grade[index]==D:
        D=D+1
    else:
        F=F+1

print(A, B, C, D, F)
```

When I input the values, they all go to the final letter even though I've inputted a range of inputs.

[image]

Comment: are you trying to compare `if Grade[index]==A:` to the letter `'A'` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
if Grade[index]==A:
```

to

```
if Grade[index]=="A":
```

etc.

You're comparing the grade to the value of the variable `A`, which is a number, so it's never equal. All your checks fail until the `else` runs.

I would also change the last bit to:

```
elif Grade[index]=="F":
    F=F+1
else:
    print("Unknown grade " + Grade[index])
```

This would warn you if the user entered invalid input instead of assuming that they entered F. In this case it might have also helped you find the bug.

Comment: Thank you so much, completely overlooked that

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because every time `else` part is getting executed. To correct this, you should compare `Grade[index] == 'A'` and not `Grade[index] == A`

The right code would be:

```
Grade = [""]*20
A=0
B=0
C=0
D=0
F=0

for index in range (20):
    Grade[index]=str(input("Input A, B, C, D or F: "))

print (Grade)

for index in range(20):
    if Grade[index]=='A':
        A=A+1
    elif Grade[index]=='B':
        B=B+1
    elif Grade[index]=='C':
        C=C+1
    elif Grade[index]=='D':
        D=D+1
    else:
        F=F+1

print(A, B, C, D, F)
```